# objective C cosine

Tags: objective-c

I'm just facing weird problem with cos function in objective c. I have the xcode 4.1.1 with iOS 4.3 SDK installed.

I'm calculating the cos of a number:

```
y= cos(x*M_PI/180)
```

this returns correct answer for almost all numbers except for 90 degree.

```
y=cos(90*M_PI/180)
```

y is 6.12323e-17! which is not correct. it should be 0.

the NSLog shows something different:

```
operand=cos(operand * M_PI / 180);
NSLog(@"cos: %d", operand);
```

result:
    cos: -832086752

I don't get. Can someone explain it please?

Comment: 6.12323e-17 is very close to zero. I wonder what cos(pi) gives you for an answer... how close to neg 1? also have you tried to see if (3/2) pi is the same problem? operand=cos(operand * M_PI / 180);
for this... try using different variable names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic isn't precise. `90*M_PI/180` is not exactly π/2 because floating-point hardware can't represent transcendental numbers exactly.

The result in `NSLog` is because `operand` is (I presume) a `float` or `double`, and you've told `NSLog` to interpret it as an `int` (`%d`). Use `%f` or `%g` instead.

Comment: thanks i missed that. i use now %.f and it shows 0 in nslog output. but the uilabel still shows 6.12323e-17. i have to see what can be done to get the correct value
the cos(89.9*M_PI/180)=0.00174533 in uilabel
cos(M_PI)=-1 in uilabel

Comment: for the uilabel (display)
display.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
thats it ;-)